# import Task in android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, task

I'm currently learning Android and Java and I am having some issues with importing.
Actually I have downloaded tutorial videos for Android. In them the person declare this:

```
Task t = new Task(taskname);
```

in java.class file ...

So eclipse gives him the error and then a red line occurs below Task and then when he hover on the task this line comes up :

```
import Task (with his package name)
```

but in my eclipse when I hover on this line this library or import line is not coming up .Where is the problem? I think there is may be some file that I haven't downloaded.

Comment: Yes your missing some file from his library/project

Comment: i think may b this library comes with a android eclipse package ? dont u think .. i dont think so he has manually write it ..

Comment: As far as I know, there is no Task class in the Android SDK. Can you provide the package name Task class is supposed to be in? Or, the link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I think no Task class in SDK...see in the example it might be the task name he gave.U try manually writing it! And check whether the error goes!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new package under `src` say for example `com.glen.tasks_manager.tasks` and add a java class inside named `Task.java`, so that when you hover to the task code it will provide an import for the package name you just have created including the new java class name.